# How to install SiS 771/671 video drivers on 13.10?

Tags: video, 13.10, sis-graphics

I've been trying for sometime to install SiS 771/671 PCIE drivers and couldn't find any info. Sis web page doesn't have a specific driver for this board, I has drivers only for Sis 650/740 and 630/730 boards and Redhat only. 
Anyone has any idea on how I install these drivers ?

Thanks :)

Comment: You've to install driver provided by Xorg. It would be already installed in your system. The `xserver-xorg-video-sis` driver which is provided by Xorg works for all types of sis display cards.. The Synaptic says about `xserver-xorg-video-sis`: **This package provides the driver for all SiS and XGI Volari cards.** If its not installed already you can install by: `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-sis`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NOTE: This answer does not work anymore for versions of Ubuntu after 14.10.

**The display driver for sis would be already installed in Ubuntu**

`xserver-xorg-video-sis` is the display driver for all Sis and XGI video driver.

To check if this is installed or not you can execute this command:

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video-sis
```

If it doesn't list any value then you can install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-sis
```

You can find more about the SIS display driver at [X.org](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/sis.4.html) site.

<sub>**Source:** [X.org Foundation](http://www.x.org/wiki/)</sub>

In addition to this this link would help you:

- https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/sis