# Grub doesn't load despite many reinstalls and boot-repair

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu

Grub simply won't load. this is my boot-repair URL: [paste2.org/YPht4Hez](http://paste2.org/YPht4Hez)

Could someone please say if they see anything wrong?

Problem description:

It's a simple setup. One HD, several linux paritions. Only one OS. It was running Lubuntu fine. Then I formatted (but kept the swap partition and created new /home partition) and installed a new version of Lubutnu and now the bios runs through memory check but never loads grub. It just stops loading and I get a black screen, although the HD seems to be running.

If I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> it briefly says "grub loading" but it never loads and I again get a black screen. If I keep pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, after many reboots then it loads Lubuntu. I have tried reinstalling Lubuntu, then Linux Mint, then back to Lubuntu, and still have the same problem.

I tried boot-repair too. My log is here: [paste2.org/YPht4Hez](http://paste2.org/YPht4Hez)

Please help. This is just crazy. I've never had such a confounding issue. Thank you.

Comment: I do not see anything specific wrong. Often better with such a small drive to keep /home inside / (root) as one partition to share unused space. But I do see SIS video which now is very old. That may need drivers or help working but do not know what SIS driver Lubuntu now has. http://askubuntu.com/questions/507118/which-ubuntu-version-works-fine-with-sis-driver-671-771 I do see this driver in my 16.04 install: `xserver-xorg-video-sis`  Try installing: `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-sis`